# Proximity Sensor Duration (Android)

Tags: java, android, sensors, proximity

In the Android API, does anyone know a way to determine how long a proximity sensor is in a given state?

For example, I would like for the screen to turn off only if the proximity sensor senses something close to it for more than 2 consecutive seconds.

My current code reads the proximity sensor state just fine, but it immediately turns off the screen.  I would like to wait longer to prevent an accidental finger swipe in front of the sensor from turning off the screen.  Thanks!

Comment: you should execute your code when the time difference between the eveent.timestamp is more than 2 seconds,this would sove your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can start a service in background, which collects data from your onSensorChanged() - method (from [SensorEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html)).

Given to that data you can make some if-cases to determine the sensor state.

Comment: Thanks! I've never used these before, but I'll give them a look and see if I can make something work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using system.currentTimeMillis() to count for how long you want and then turn off the screen when the timer his 0

Comment: I think this would work as a wait, but I want to make sure that in that interval from the onSensorChanged to the end of the timer the state has been constant.